# NSMutable array of tile nodes returns null when calling it in another class

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a tmxTileMapLayer class that has this method to make tile nodes.

In the tmxTileMapLayer.h I have an array like so.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *tileArray;
```

In the tmxTileMapLayer.m

```
-(void)createNodesFromLayer:(TMXLayer *)layer
{
JSTileMap *map = layer.map;
//1
for (int w = 0 ; w < self.gridSize.width; ++w) {
    for(int h = 0; h < self.gridSize.height; ++h) {

        CGPoint coord = CGPointMake(w, h);
        NSInteger tileGid =
        [layer.layerInfo tileGidAtCoord:coord];
        if(!tileGid)
            continue;
if ([map propertiesForGid:tileGid] [@"grapple"]) {
            grapple = [SKSpriteNode node];
            grapple = [layer tileAtCoord:coord];
            grapple.position = CGPointMake(grapple.position.x, grapple.position.y);
            grapple.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
            grapple.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0;

            [_tileArray addObject:grapple];

            NSLog(@"%@",_tileArray);
        }
```

if I Nslog here I get the positions of the tiles.

Now in my main class which is called MyScene

```
  -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
   if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.scene.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

    [self createWorld];

    tileArrayCopy = [[TmxTileMapLayer alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [tileArrayCopy.tileArray mutableCopy];

    [_worldNode addChild:tileArrayCopy];

    NSLog(@"%@",newArray);

       }
return self;
}
```

if I NSLong now with newArray I get Null. :/

here is the create world method.

```
 - (TileMapLayer *)createScenery
 {
_tileMap = [JSTileMap mapNamed:@"level.tmx"];
return [[TmxTileMapLayer alloc]
        initWithTmxLayer:[_tileMap layerNamed:@"circle"]];
 }

 - (TileMapLayer *)grappleStuff
 {
return [[TmxTileMapLayer alloc]
        initWithTmxLayer:[_tileMap layerNamed:@"grapple"]];
 }


- (void)createWorld {
_bgLayer = [self createScenery];
_fgLayer = [self bouncDynamic];

_worldNode = [SKNode node];
[self addChild:_worldNode];

if (_tileMap) {
    [_worldNode addChild:_tileMap];
}


[_worldNode addChild:_bgLayer];
[_worldNode addChild:_fgLayer];

SKNode *bounds = [SKNode node];
bounds.physicsBody =
[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:
 CGRectMake(0, 0,

            _bgLayer.layerSize.width,
            _bgLayer.layerSize.height)];
bounds.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = PCBoundaryCategory;
bounds.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = PCPlayerCategory | PCDestruction;
[_worldNode addChild:bounds];

_bgLayer.zPosition = 1;
_tileMap.zPosition = 1;

[self grappleStuff];
[self hazardStuff];
[self destructionStuff];


}
```

thank you for your help!! I'm super stuck!

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the Mutable Array inside the init method TmxTileMapLayer class or you can do this.

```
   tileArrayCopy = [[TmxTileMapLayer alloc] init];
   tileArrayCopy.tileArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   NSMutableArray *newArray = tileArrayCopy.tileArray;
```

I think what happens is when you do this

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [tileArrayCopy.tileArray mutableCopy];
```

the tileArray is nil and when you call mutableCopy guess whats gonna happen (passing message to nil and what does objective-c does?).

Comment: No, you shouldn't allocate `.tileArray` like that; it's not the responsibility of the caller.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thats why I told him both options. If TmxTileMapLayer doesn't do it then he has to initialize it for it to work.

Comment: @chuthan20 So i tired it out, I still get nothing. I tired different things, I either get Null, or nothing from an nslog. Oddly if I use an instance variable instead of a strong property in the TmxTileMapLayer class, I do get one of the tile positions (the last one) when I nslog in the MyScene class.

Comment: Its really hard to help you when I only know some bits of your program. Maybe try posting what you tried.

Comment: @chuthan20 sorry about that, I'm still learning. :) I actually figured out a workout around. I instead created the tiles in the MyScene class, since I only need like 5 - 10 per level. I used the sprites Frame to get the effect I wanted. worked perfectly!! thank you for the the help! I still eventually want to figure this out later tho.